# Linked List question

Tags: c, linked-list

what does this mean?

```
void add(struct node **root, int x)
 {
      struct node *conductor;
      if(*root==NULL)
      {
          (*root)=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          (*root)->x=x;
          (*root)->next=NULL ;         
      }
      else
      {
          conductor = *root;
          while(conductor->next!=NULL)
          {
               conductor = conductor -> next;             
          }                
          conductor->next=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
          conductor->next->x=x;
          conductor->next->next=NULL;
     } 
  }
```

the `conductor=Conductor->next;` what does that mean? I need to feed my curiosity and I want to know if my idea about is true

it is mine, I just want to make sure if my thought on was correct, I am having doubts on my code all the time

Comment: your previous question was supposedly about "[your] linked list code" (quoted from the text of your previous question...) if you don't understand this code, how can it be yours ? do your homework, stop copy/pasting and start thinking a little bit to understand programming !

Comment: code looks veeeery similar to this: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Comment: Also, if you cannot understand it, just ask it. You move yourself down when you are trying to keep yourself up, or upper like this.

Answer (score 1):

A linked-list is constructed by a serie of object, each one pointing to the next element in the list. The line `conductor = conductor->next;` just update the `conductor` variable (that point to a list element, a `struct node`) to point to the next element in the list.

Update: the wikipedia article about [linked-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) offer good visual representation of a such a data structure.

Comment: can you provide any graphical or pictorial representation my idea on it is still blurred

Answer (score 0):

`conductor -> next` is just a way of writing `(*conductor).next`.

Since conductor is a pointer to struct, you can't access it's members by conductor.next directly, in this case, it means that `conductor` will now point to the next element in the list (the one that `conductor->next` pointed to before)

Comment: do I get this right? the conductor=conductor->next, will become the head?

Comment: It will not become the head of the list. The head will still be root, but the while loop will make `conductor` to point to the last node (not including NULL of course..).

Comment: In other words, the while loop actually says: while conductor is not pointing to the last node (conductor->next != NULL, meaning there is another node) make conductor point to  the next node.

Answer (score 0):

`conductor=*root` sets the pointer conductor to point to the first element in the list root

`conductor=conductor->next` sets the pointer conductor to point to the next element in the list root.

As compared to an array with length of one, the first line would set a pointer to the 0th element of an array, while the next line would set the pointer to the 1st element. If this does not make sense, you should read up on linked lists, and why you use them compared to say arrays.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you asked:

```
conductor=conductor->next means that the means that the conductor will move
```

to the next memory location.

For example :

```
void insert(struct node **ptr)
{
  struct node *tmp;
  tmp=*ptr;
  tmp=tmp->next;
}
```

tmp is now pointing to the starting memory location of the linked list as we can point the pointer to anywhere if it is not a const pointer.

tmp=tmp->next means that it is pointing to the next memory location which depends upon the compiler if the sizeof pointer is 4bytes it will move to 4 bytes.